# How to get the number of users in Windows?

Tags: c, winapi

Is there a `WinAPI` function to know how many users there are (and even better their names as well) in Windows?

Would an alternative solution to be to check what folders exists in the `C:\Users` folder?

Comment: What do you mean by #users? - #logged on to a server, #users in a domain?  c:\users would just contain a snapshot of user prefs from users that have logged in to a particular machine.

Comment: use  Win32_UserAccount class of WMI API.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I am talking about the user accounts that you create when you go to control panel and choose "Add or remove user accounts". BTW I am talking about the desktop edition of Windows (not the server edition that is).

Answer (score 2):

use [NetUserEnum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [NetQueryDisplayInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
    PVOID pv;
    DWORD n, i = 0, err;
    do 
    {
        switch (err = NetQueryDisplayInformation(0, 1, i, MAXDWORD, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, &n, &pv))
        {
        case 0:
        case ERROR_MORE_DATA:
            if (n)
            {
                PNET_DISPLAY_USER p = (PNET_DISPLAY_USER)pv;

                do
                {
                    i = p->usri1_next_index;

                    DbgPrint("<%S> <%S>\n", p->usri1_name, p->usri1_comment);

                } while (p++, --n);
            }
            NetApiBufferFree(pv);
            break;
        }
    } while (err == ERROR_MORE_DATA);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use PowerShell commands to get a list of local machine users.

```
$LocalAccount = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select Name, LocalAccount FROM WIN32_UserAccount WHERE LocalAccount=true"
```

***Or:***

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | select -expand name
```